googlesheets4 not authorizing after RStudio update
I just updated my R and R Studio (now running R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31) and R Studio Version 2023.09.1+494)
I tried troubleshooting from answers given here, here, and here, but it's not working and/or the answer provided is over my head.
I have the following code in a script that I use very regularly and has been working fine before the update.
library(googlesheets4)
googlesheets4::gs4_auth()
2

(The "2" is there because I select the 2nd email in the list.)
Now when i run the same code I get this error message:

googlesheets4::gs4_auth()
Error in googlesheets4::gs4_auth():
! Can't get Google credentials.
ℹ Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session?
Consider:
• Call gs4_deauth() to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
• Call gs4_auth() directly with all necessary specifics.
ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
ℹ https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

It says it can't get the google credentials. I am not running in a non-interactive session - in the past, I've gotten the question do I want to authorize and it brings me to the browser to do so (which I assume is an "interactive" session).
I can only assume this is because I updated R/R Studio and it can no longer find the stored credential - but then why isn't it just bringing me to the browser to re-authorize?
Anyone have any experience with this error? Thank you!

You probably lost google authorization after R update. Hope this article can help.
